# How do I turn a JsonElement into Json without the members tag?

Tags: android, parsing, gson, json

I have a method that parses the differences between two `JsonElement`s and then returns a `JsonElement` that represents an object containing only the differences between the two elements.

I am then attempting to send the returned `JsonElement` via API PUT request and generically parse the response to an object type. The problem is that `JsonElement`s parse to `Json` with the members tag in front of all of its contents.

For Example:

```
{"members":{"id":1172327,"assets":[{"id":436379,"licenseState":"MI","odometer":"12345"}]}}
```

How can I remove the members tag from the `JsonElement`.  I would prefer not to do it manually. I tried `JsonElement.getAsJsonObject()` and that fails. I also attempted to get the `JsonElement` as a `JsonArray` (`JsonElement.getAsJsonArray().get(0)`) but this failed because the `JsonElement` is not a `JsonArray`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

/** Assuming json_string is your json string **/

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json_string);

JSONObject jsonMembers = jsonObj.getJSONObject("members");

//will return "{"id":1172327,"assets":[{"id":436379,"licenseState":"MI","odometer":"12345"}]}"
Log.d("Members only:",String.valueOf(jsonMembers));
```

Note: Make sure to surround with try/catch in case it's not valid json!!

Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

Comment: JsonObject test = new JsonObject(jsonString); 
The constructor JsonObject(String) is undefined

Comment: @user2962960 You need the correct import. I've updated the code. If you're using eclipse, you can hover over the red underlined text, and click "Import _____" in the popup and it will add the required imports.

Comment: I am using JsonElements (gson) and not JSONElements
EDIT: I can use JsonObject test = JsonELement.getAsJsonObject(); to achieve a similar result but after checking test.getAsJsonObject("members") returns as null

Comment: @user2962960 That's fine. It shouldn't make a difference. Gson is just a library to convert objects to JSON. Just take the JSON that the (Gson) library spits out, cast it as string, and drop it into a new "JSONObject"

Answer (score 1):

What if you just do `JsonElement.getJSONObject("members")` ? That will grab the element with the key "members"

Comment: JsonElements do not have a method .getAsJsonObject(string) only .getAsJsonObject()

I am trying to convert it to a JsonObject, then grab the "members" element now. I will Edit with results.

EDIT:
    JsonObject test = JsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

test.getAsJsonObject("members") returns as null.